# Is there a way to configure Zend Studio 12 to format Laravel/Blade code

Tags: laravel, formatting, laravel-blade, zend-studio

I hope this doesn't come as a trivial or subjective question. But I am working on migrating several basic PHP projects to use the Laravel framework, and am using Zend Studio 12 as my IDE.

There are several times during my development where I would like to right click and do the **Source > Format** option to clean up my code. However, while it will clean up the HTML and PHP beautifully, it offsets all of my Blade code from

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ Form::label('gender', 'Gender') }}
        {{ Form::text('date_of_birth', Input::old('gender'), array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
    </div>
```

to

```
    <div class="col-md-4">{{ Form::label('gender', 'Gender') }} {{
        Form::text('date_of_birth', Input::old('gender'),
        array('class'=>'form-control')) }}</div>
```

I've tried poking around the **Project > Properties > PHP > Code Style > Formatter > Configure Workspace Settings** but I'm not sure how to go about doing my own custom formatting (or finding existing templates that could do this). Is it possible to do a straight forward configuration for this, or is it an instance of just having to suck it up and format it manually?

Comment: Use PhpStorm, good luck. (my two cents)

Comment: I will have to agree with @Kyslik.  I used ZS for _years_ and just lived with the poor performance, cluttered UI, buggy VCS support, etc.  I just told myself "you are a professional, and this is a professional-grade IDE. so use it!"  One day I finally had enough and gave PhpStorm a _try_, after 30 minutes my mind was made up.  I'll never use ZS again.  Best of luck!